Help with the proof of this statement
Let $ f : [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a bounded function. Then for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$such that for any partition $D$ of the interval $[a, b]$ with norm $\nu(D)$ smaller than $\delta$, the following holds:
$$
\left| U(f, D) - \int_a^b \overline{f}(x) \, dx \right| < \epsilon.
$$
The upper Riemann integral is the infimum over all partitions of the upper sum. The left side is an upper sum with respect to partition $D$. The infimum on all the sums is given by:
$\inf_{D} U(f, D)$
The right side is the upper integral, which is the infimum over all partitions of the upper sum:
$\overline{\int_a^b} f(x) \, dx = \inf_{D} U(f, D)$ 

The way I would do it is to get an arbitrary upper sum within $\epsilon/2$ of the integral.

By definition of $\overline{\int_a^b} f(x) $, for any $\epsilon>0$, one can find a partition $D_{\epsilon}$ such that $\overline{\int_a^b} f(x)+\epsilon>U(f, D_{\epsilon})$. This yields $$\left| U(f, D_{\epsilon}) - \int_a^b \overline{f}(x) \, dx \right| < \epsilon.$$ You shoud be able to move on from there.
